# Scala convert a string to raw

Tags: regex, scala, rawstring

I know raw String can be declared as:

```
val foo: String = """foo"""
```

or

```
val foo: String = raw"foo"
```

However, if I have a string type val, how can I convert it to raw? For example:

```
// val toBeMatched = "line1: foobarfoo\nline2: lol"
def regexFoo(toBeMatched: String) = {
     val pattern = "^.*foo[\\w+]foo.*$".r
     val pattern(res) = toBeMatched  /* <-- this line induces an exception 
       since Scala translates '\n' in string 'toBeMatched'. I want to convert
       toBeMatched to raw string before pattern matching */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your simple case, you can do this:

```
val a = "this\nthat"
a.replace("\n", "\\n")  // this\nthat
```

For a more general solution, use [StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava(java.lang.String)) in Apache commons.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("this\nthat")  // this\nthat
```

---

**Note:** your code doesn't actually make any sense.  Aside from the fact that `String toBeMatched`  is invalid Scala syntax, your regex pattern is set up such that it will only match the string `"foo"`, not `"foo\n"` or `"foo\\n"`, and `pattern(res)` only makes sense if your regex is attempting to capture something, which it's not.

Maybe (?!) you meant something like this?:

```
def regexFoo(toBeMatched: String) = {
  val pattern = """foo(.*)""".r
  val pattern(res) = toBeMatched.replace("\n", "\\n") 
}
regexFoo("foo\n")  //  "\\n"
```