# Why escape character is not working when string is stored in variable?

Tags: string, scala

Here it is printed without line break, OK

```
scala> println(raw"Hello \n World")
Hello \n World
```

But, how is line break working here on storing in a value and also even after using `raw`

```
scala> val word = "Hello \n World"
scala> println(raw"$word")
Hello 
 World
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scala convert a string to raw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109578/scala-convert-a-string-to-raw)

Answer (score 3):

To clarify on @Joel Berkeley's answer:

When using the `raw` interpolator, as in `raw"\n"`, you get a String which has two charaters in it, verbatim, a <kbd>\</kbd> and a <kbd>n</kbd>.

Now, when you have a normal String, e.g. `"\n"`, you get a String with a single character, namely a "line feed" <kbd>LF</kbd>, ASCII code 10.

Then, if you embed that into a new string, using whatever interpolator you want (ie. it does not matter whether you use `s`, `f`, or `raw`), you still get the same character no matter what since the value of the string is inserted in the resulting string.

Just to reiterate, there is no "raw format", you always just get a String, it's just a different interpretation of the character of the string itself when it is constructed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess the string is defined as raw at compile time not runtime, so you'd need to

```
val word = raw"Hello \n World"
println(s"$word")
```

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25632924/5986907), which doesn't appear to cover this.

Comment: But if declared `val word = raw"Hello \n World"`, it will always be in raw format @Joel Berkeley

Comment: @phineas why do you need to use both? might help solve your problem